# Can I force a remote hg repo to do hg update after I push to it?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, synchronization

I am writing code in a mercurial repository on my laptop, which I then push to a server via `hg push`, and then on the server, I run `hg update` and then run my newly-written code on the server. Is there any way to force the repo on the server to be automatically updated to the latest revision after I push to it from my laptop, so I can save the step?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Look at the following entry on HG faq : [Any way to 'hg push' and have an automatic 'hg update' on the remote server?](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2FCommonProblems.Any_way_to_.27hg_push.27_and_have_an_automatic_.27hg_update.27_on_the_remote_server.3F).

As per the Faq, you can use the hooks to automatically call "hg update" after a push

```
[hooks]
changegroup = hg update >&2
```

This goes in .hg/hgrc on the remote repository. Output has to be redirected to stderr (or /dev/null), because stdout is used for the data stream.

Comment: @Ryan Thompson: Does this serve your purpose?

Comment: Almost have written the same :-) +1

Comment: Would --quiet also suppress all stdout output?